# Sum of an x^2 function for values from 1 to n

Tags: python, sum, new-operator

I am new to python and trying to create a function for the sum of squares between 1 and n. I've tried

```
def squared(x, n):
    tot = sum(x ** 2 for x in range (1, n+1))
    return tot
```

when I then try to check using

```
print(squared([1.2, 2.3]))
```

I get type error

```
squared() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

Comment: You are missing the second argument `n` of your function. Also, why are you passing `x`?

Comment: Your function expects two arguments, a list `x` and a count `n`.  But it doesn't use the values of `x` at all.  All it uses is `n`, so change it to expect a single number as its sole argument.  The values in the list serve no purpose.